# Avoid target and add DISCLAIMER files while deploying source packs to nexus

Tags: maven, nexus, release-management

I used following for uploading artifacts to nexus repository(with other parameters.

```
mvn clean release:perform
```

Problem i face is that the source artifacts contain target directory. I also want to add DISCLAIMER file along with LICENCE and NOTICE files which are already get bundled.

Is there a way to avoid target and include DISCLAIMER using release plugin parameter or pom.xml configuration?

Thanks.

Comment: If your releases contain target folder something is going wrong.

Comment: Do you mean something wrong in the way it builds? or release plugin configuration?

Comment: Can you show the appropriate pom file?

Answer (score 0):

Following maven source plugin did the trick. It needed additional "org.apache:apache-incubator-disclaimer-resource-bundle:1.1" resourceBundle for adding DISCLAIMER files.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                    <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                            <resourceBundles>
                                    <resourceBundle>org.apache:apache-incubator-disclaimer-resource-bundle:1.1</resourceBundle>
                                    <resourceBundle>org.apache:apache-jar-resource-bundle:1.4</resourceBundle>
                            </resourceBundles>
                    </configuration>
                     </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Following configuration of the maven-source-plugin was able to pack source jars without target.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```